# Needing Kendo UI Pop-Up Notification when Inline Editing Grid Create is submitted but does not pass validation in controller

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Basically, once a new item is created in the Grid UI, I am doing a check against our database to make sure that there is a match between the `SSINumber` / `DataSourceID` pair. If there is not, I am trying to make a popup to notify the user that the values they entered are not valid.

My `Index.cshtml` is:

```
@model IEnumerable<SSI_Dashboard.Models.FacOverrideObject>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<b class="FloatRight SearchTopMarginExtra">Search List For: </b>
<input type="search" id="searchbox" class="SearchRight SearchTopMargin" />
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                                .Name("grid")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.DataSourceId);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.FacilityOverrideId).Width(120);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.SsiNumber).Width(120);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.NPI).Width(120);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.NameOverrideValue).Width(200);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.MembershipOrganizationName).Width(200);
                                    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
                                })
                                .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).ConfirmDelete("Delete this entry?").DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Procede to this Facility Override?"))
                                .Sortable()
                                .Groupable()
                                .Scrollable(s => s.Height(650))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.FacilityOverrideId);
                                    })
                                    .Events(events =>
                                    {
                                        events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");
                                    })
                                    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "FacOverrides"))
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "FacOverrides"))
                                    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "FacOverrides"))
                                    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "FacOverrides"))
                                ).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:700" })
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    function onRequestEnd(e) {
        if (e.type == "update") {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //change event
        $("#searchbox").keyup(function () {
            var val = $('#searchbox').val();
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
                logic: "or",
                filters: [
                    {
                        field: "NameOverrideValue",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    },
                    {
                        field: "MembershipOrganizationName",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    }
                ]
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

My `Create()` method in my model is:

```
     public static bool Create(FacOverrideObject fOverride)
            {
                bool inShardA = false;
                bool inShardB = false;
                bool inShardC = false;

                var returnVal = new SqlParameter();
                returnVal.ParameterName = "@Return";
                returnVal.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                returnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                using (ShardA sa = new ShardA())
                {
                     foreach(var row in sa.DataSourceSSINumbers.ToList())
                    {
                        if (row.DataSourceID == fOverride.DataSourceId && row.SSINumber == fOverride.SsiNumber)
                            inShardA = true;
                    }
                }

                using (ShardB sb = new ShardB())
                {
                    foreach (var row in sb.DataSourceSSINumbers.ToList())
                    {
                        if (row.DataSourceID == fOverride.DataSourceId && row.SSINumber == fOverride.SsiNumber)
                            inShardB = true;
                    }
                }

                using (ShardC sc = new ShardC())
                {
                    foreach (var row in sc.DataSourceSSINumbers.ToList())
                    {
                        if (row.DataSourceID == fOverride.DataSourceId && row.SSINumber == fOverride.SsiNumber)
                            inShardC = true;
                    }
                }

                if (inShardA || inShardB || inShardC)
                {
                    using (FacilityOverrides db = new FacilityOverrides())
                    {
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec InsertFacilityOverride @DataSourceId = " + fOverride.DataSourceId.ToString() +
                                                        ", @SsiNumber = " + fOverride.SsiNumber.ToString() +
                                                        ", @NPI = " + fOverride.NPI.ToString() +
                                                        ", @NameOverrideValue = '" +
                                                        fOverride.NameOverrideValue + "'");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

And the `Create()` method in my controller is:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, FacOverrideObject fOverride)
{
    if (fOverride != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FacilityOverride.Create(fOverride);
    }

    return Json(new[] { fOverride }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

I was trying to create a pop-up from the controller but have not had much success as everything I can find to create popups is done within `Index.cshtml` using JavaScript. That will not work for me, however, as this is conditional based on results from validation results from the Model. I have passed the results from the Model to the controller via the return values, but still cannot find any resource on if/how I can create a popup from outside of `Index`, or even create it from `Index` based on the conditions I am checking.

Comment: [Here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid) is one technique for handling server side errors.

Comment: Thank you Steve! I guess my wording on google wasn't as good as yours.

Comment: Actually it is a technique I have used. A bit tricky to setup, but it does work.